# ARRAYFORMULA repeating results of VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I've been forced to change a formula in my spreadsheet and can't seem to get the `ARRAYFORMULA` to fill down the column without repeating the same result.

Here is the code that works in a single row:

```excel
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(QUERY(coreAbilities!$A$2:$E,"SELECT B,C,D,E where A = '"&VLOOKUP(C2:C,unitData!$C$2:$D,2,)&"'",0)&":"),":"))
```

​I've tried wrapping it in a `VLOOKUP`, but nothing seems to get the job done.

Basically, I'm searching a table of 5 columns and finding a match to a name, however, the name is not the same between these two tables.  The name I'm searching has to first be matched to it's "code name" in another table and *then* I can search the final table.  On top of that, each name has 3-5 matches, each with 5 values.  So simply using a `VLOOKUP` doesn't seem to do the trick.

I've tried `VLOOKUP` and `FILTER` in hopes of making this easier on myself, but the only formula I can manage to get the results I need (at least in the proper order) is by using `QUERY`.

I'm not married to the method I'm using, but it's gotten me this far, so I've just been trying to force it through.

Here's [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y5GgL9ZwCDVUk7v06WAl2g3KqersH51KTH7F12MqY-0/edit#gid=940565536&range=H2) 
Heros!H2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUERY` does **not** support **arrays/ranges** inside itself under string parameters.

[image: 0]

the only possible way is to use regex capabilities within `QUERY` like:

[image: 0]

however `TEXTJOIN` belongs to a group of formulae that are limited to 50000 character input, eg. this won't work with your massive arrays. therefore double `VLOOKUP` is your friend. but as you noticed `VLOOKUP` can output always only the first found result and every next finds will be just a clones/repeats of the first match.

[image: 0]

so the trick is to append  a counter to the vlooked up value which will force new finds instead of cloning previous finds:

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, unitData!$C$2:$D, 2, 0)), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, unitData!$C$2:$D, 2, 0)), ROW(M2:M), "<="&ROW(M2:M))&
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, unitData!$C$2:$D, 2, 0)),
 {COUNTIFS(coreAbilities!A2:A, coreAbilities!A2:A, ROW(coreAbilities!A2:A), "<="&
 ROW(coreAbilities!A2:A))&coreAbilities!A2:A, coreAbilities!B2:E}, {2,3,4,5}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, unitData!$C$2:$D, 2, 0)), 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({coreAbilities!A2:A&"♦", 
 "♠"&coreAbilities!B2:B&"♠"&coreAbilities!C2:C&"♠"&coreAbilities!D2:D&"♠"&coreAbilities!E2:E,
 coreAbilities!C2:C}, "select Col1,max(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,999^99)), "♦"), 2, 0)), "♠"))), "offset 1", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: But this misses out on the other matches, no? The ones I assumed were supposed to go to the right (but were not super clear in the question). i.e. flow of the force is only one out of four skills, where the remaining three should come to the right of column K

Comment: I tried this formula, but it only appears to give the first match for each character (as far as I could tell, anyway [on mobile, atm]). And it seems to keep crashing the mobile app, so I deleted it for now. While the formula doesn’t completely work, If you look at the last copy of the sheet, that one shows all matches for the first character. I might need to add one more group for other characters though. EDIT: the app seems to crash regardless...

Comment: @a-burge as I understood the OP's question the issue was that arrayformula was repeating every next found match downwards. eg. this proposed solution counters that. as you can notice i251, i252 etc... are next tier skills for given player not the first found skill repeated over whenever players name repeats

Comment: Yes, it’s a ton of data. And I see what the formula is doing now, but I don’t think that’ll be an end solution. Maybe I should create another sheet and transpose all of the coreAbilities matches to single rows. That’ll probably make things easier.

Comment: @Trey you want to list all skills per character per row? is that what are you after?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry!  I never seem to articulate it right the first time.

Comment: I knew you’d figure it out! You’re the best! And thank you for the added explanation of why my original formula wasn’t working. That stuff really helps!